# Why will this array not stop looping in c

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to display a [Vigenere Square](http://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/NSF-4/Tutorial/VIG/Vig-Base.html) but the for loop that creates it will not stop looping past the counter. You can find the loop under choice 1. Also if someone knows how to make the decrypt function to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char encrypt(char, char);
char decrypt(char, char);

int main()
{
    int choice;
    printf("What would you like to do?\n\n");
    printf("1. Show board\n");
    printf("2. Encrypt\n");
    printf("3. Decrypt\n");
    printf("4. Exit\n");

    scanf("%i", &choice);
    while(choice != 4){
        char key[9];
        char input[51];
        char decrypt[51];

        if (choice == 3 || choice == 2){
            printf("Give me a 9 character or less key in caps.\n");
            scanf("%s", &key);
            printf("Give me a 51 character or less string in caps.\n");
            scanf("%s", &input);
        }

        if (choice==1){
            int i, j;
            for(i=0;i<=25;i++){
                for(j=0;j<=25;j++){
                    printf("%c  ", encrypt((char) i, (char) j));
                }
                printf("\n");
            }

        } else if (choice == 2){
            int i;
            char text_crypt[51];

            for(i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++){
                text_crypt[i] = encrypt(input[i], key[i % strlen(key)]);
            }
            printf("cyphertext is: %s\n", text_crypt);
        } else if (choice == 3){
            int i;
            char text_crypt[51];

            for(i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++){
                text_crypt[i] = encrypt(input[i], key[i % strlen(key)]);
            }
            printf("cyphertext is: %s\n", text_crypt);

        }
    }
return 0;
}


char encrypt(char x, char y){
    return 65+((x+y)%26);
}

char decrypt(char x, char y){
    return 90-((x+y)%26);
}
```

I am trying to display a Vigenere Square but the for loop that creates it will not stop looping past the counter. You can find the loop under choice 1. Also if someone knows how to make the decrypt function to work.

Comment: If you want to enter `9` characters, `char key[9+1];` ... `scanf("%9s", key);`

Comment: Are you saying that when the user enters `1`, the program goes into an infinite loop, or do you mean that it is looping to `i==26` or `j==26`?

Comment: `scanf("%i", &choice);` is required at the end of block of `while(choice != 4)`.

Comment: `printf("cyphertext is: %s\n", text_crypt);` --> `text_crypt[i] = 0; printf("cyphertext is: %s\n", text_crypt);`

Comment: Also "Decrypt"(choice : 3) is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The loop doesn't end because choice is not equal to 4. You need to have the user input part inside the while loop so after each iteration it asks again for the user choice.

Change `int choice;` to `int choice = 0;` (something other than 4) and move

```
printf("What would you like to do?\n\n");
printf("1. Show board\n");
printf("2. Encrypt\n");
printf("3. Decrypt\n");
printf("4. Exit\n");
scanf("%i", &choice);
```

into your loop.